# Custom validation attribute for model Data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

is there any approach in customizing data annotations just like adding [Uppercase],[Lowercase],[ProperCase] annotations in the model to convert the model in the said cases.???
 i Have tried using modelbinder and it only to be set just one data annotations what i want to achieved is to have a model like this:

```
[Display(Name="Agent Code", Prompt =  "Agent Code")]
[CustomAttributes(Case="Uppecase", IsTrim=false)]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = ModelConstants.L_MSG_REQUIRED)]
[StringLength(10)]
public string agent_cd { get; set; }
```

any idea or suggestions how to achieved my desired output??

Answer (score 3):

Has a way to do it, create your own annotation, like this:

```
namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
{
    public class MakeMeUpperCase : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            try
            {
                validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(validationContext.DisplayName)
                .SetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, value.ToString().ToUpper() , null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return null;
      }
   }
}
```

And your property:

```
[MakeMeUpperCase]
public string TurnUpper { get; set; }
```

Comment: I already solved my problem. i can also convert it now into Upper proper and lower case, And also it can be trimmed thanks,,